# Nginx rewrite overwrites index

Tags: nginx

I have set my index to view/index.html with
`index view/index.html`

I want to rewrite urls of the form localhost/route to be handled by controller/index.php but adding `rewrite /* /controller/index.php` also redirects localhost to the controller index overwriting the index previously set.

i have also tried it with `rewrite /([a-z]+) /controller/index.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appearently also rewrites localhost the controller index because the rewrite rule isn't specific enough.
the solution is:
`rewrite /(a-zA-Z0-9_-)$ /controller/index.php`
where $ means "end of the line" this will mean that whatever it match it will be at the end of the url

Comment: this will not rewrite some thing like localhost/some-route.php however, and add the dot in the regex will overwrite nginx's index once again